# How many addresses are there now with segwit?

Tags: address

Could you help me understand if with **segwit** activated do we have more available private keys and addresses in the Bitcoin universe?

With *Legacy [1...], Compatible [3...] and Bech32 [bc1...] addresses* do we have **3x more** possibilities ?

Thank you.

Comment: P2SH has existed for half a decade, it’s not “compatible”, it’s a re use of existing technology in a new way.

Answer (score 3):

- There are 2<sup>160</sup> P2PKH addresses.
- There are 2<sup>160</sup> P2SH addresses
- There are 2<sup>160</sup> P2WPKH addresses.
- There are 2<sup>256</sup> P2WSH addresses.
- There are 16 defined but unused witness versions which can be encoded by BIP173 (Bech32) addresses, each with data length 2 to 40 bytes. That's 16*256/255*(256<sup>40</sup> - 256) =~ 2<sup>324.006</sup>.

That's 2144363455669619533814323684450670475181580230986810095535626033037852598144837730344835022389248 in total.

The number of private keys has not changed; that's still slightly less than 2<sup>256</sup>, namely 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336. Only the number of ways to use them increased.